# Spark Python map function: Error in encoding utf-8

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, encoding, utf-8

I've been trying to process a textfile with Python. My textfile is in the native language of Vietnamese people, which use the UTF-8. After I use the map function, the output seems to be out of format. I've separated the code and output it step by step. I notice that the encoding went wrong after the map word: (word, 1). To be more precise, upto output7.txt, the text was: 
Đức
đã
ngã
gục

However, at output 8, the encoding went wrong:

(u'\u0110\u1ee9c', 1)
(u'\u0111\xe3', 1)
(u'ng\xe3', 1)
(u'g\u1ee5c', 1)

it's supposed to be 
(Đức, 1)
(đã, 1)
(ngã, 1)
(gục, 1)

I've tried to fix this bug for 5 hours, but haven't found anything really useful. Can anyone tells me why the Map function wrecked everything, while the similar FlatMap function works fine?

Thank you. Below is my source code.

```
> #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import os, sys
import codecs

conf =SparkConf().setAppName("wordcount").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

text_file = sc.textFile("outputtest/*",use_unicode=False)
dict_file = sc.textFile("keyword");

text_file.saveAsTextFile("Output6.txt")

counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
counts.saveAsTextFile("Output7.txt")

counts = counts.map(lambda word: (word.decode("utf-8"), 1)) 
counts.saveAsTextFile("Output8.txt")

counts= counts.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
dicts = dict_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(", ")) \
                 .map(lambda word: (word.replace("'","").replace(" ","_"))) 

keyword = dicts.join(counts);                

counts.saveAsTextFile("Output9.txt")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing particularly wrong with encoding here. You simply save a wrong thing. If you want to save a proper Unicode representation you should prepare one yourself:

```
counts.map(lambda x: u"({0}, {1})".format(*x)).saveAsTextFile(...)
```

Comment: thanks for the explaination, however I found it's a bit hard to understand, as I search for Python API in Spark I haven't seen the format method. could you elaborate this? thanks a lot

Comment: `format` is a standard Python string method: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Comment: I added the code and it works, I'm still trying to understand what was that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Basically difference is between taking a string representation of `(u'\u0111\xe3', 1) ` and concatenating `u'\u0111\xe3'` and `u'1'`